# d3 forced graph - hide inherited links

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created a small forced graph. Each node got an "parent" attribute which contains the "parent". If the user clicks on a parent node all childs collapse. I use a similar condition to hide the links.

```
function click(d) {
    if (boolOpacity == true) {
        nodes.filter((n) => {
            icons.filter((m) => {
                return m.parent == d.id
            }).style("display", "none")
            return  n.parent == d.id
        }).style("display", "none")

        links.filter((e) => {
            return e.target.id == d.id
        }).style("display", "none")

        boolOpacity = false 
    } else {
        nodes.filter((n) => {
            icons.filter((m) => {
                return m.parent == d.id
            }).style("display", "block")
            return n.parent == d.id
        }).style("display", "block")

        links.filter((e) => {
            return e.target.id == d.id
        }).style("display", "block")

        boolOpacity = true
        
    }
}
```

My problem is the inheritance. Currently only the direct neighbours collapse. I need a something like a d3 tree layout function for a forced graph. Where the root node collapse everything etc.

Any idea, hint or even pseudocode is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried creating a d3.hierarchy of the data, and then using root.descendants() as the input for the simulation? This way you have access to tree navigation for the nodes.

Comment: @RodrigoDivino no not at all. I am actually not aware of such functions. I will look for that. Thanks for the hint. I would use a tree layout by default but I wouldn´t be able to link childs between each other or childs to an different branch. What I actually need :/

Answer (score 0):

For sure its a quick and dirty solution. Further its necessary to add another condition in dependency of the levels but in the end it is working dynamically.

To hide:

```
links.filter((a) => {
            if(a.target.id == d.id) {
                links.filter((b) => {
                    if(b.target.id == a.source.id) {
                        links.filter((c) => {
                            return c.target.id == b.source.id
                        }).style("display", "none")
                    }
                    return b.target.id == a.source.id
                }).style("display", "none")
            }
            return a.target.id == d.id
        }).style("display", "none")
```

To display:

```
links.filter((a) => {
            if(a.target.id == d.id) {
                links.filter((b) => {
                    if(b.target.id == a.source.id) {
                        links.filter((c) => {
                            return c.target.id == b.source.id
                        }).style("display", "block")
                    }
                    return b.target.id == a.source.id
                }).style("display", "block")
            }
            return a.target.id == d.id
        }).style("display", "block")
```